# Удалить пробелы между словами введеными в EditText

Tags: android, android-edittext

Во избежании добавления не нужных пробелов в поле EditText пользователем, хочу удалить их совсем, не подскажете как это сделать?

Пример: пользователь вводит " Range - Rover"(как видно 3 пробела), в коде у меня прописано "range-rover"(0 пробелов), при сравнении мне нужно, чтобы он подводил вариант введенный пользователем к моему.

Для того,чтобы сделать все строчные я указываю .toLowerCase();

Comment: а если введут "рэнжик", "рэнжровер", "понторезка"? как пробел повлияет на правильность ввода? и откуда взялся дефис? Это к тому, что вы делаете что-то не так.

Comment: если вы введете  не предусмотренные слова/ словосочетания, то ответ не примется, если конечно этот вариант не предусмотрен. Я не стал расписывать здесь всю логику, так как к данному вопросу это не имеет отношения. А за черточку, спасибо! Использовал для наглядности.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Думаю так:

```
editText.getText().toString().toLowerCase().replaceAll(" ", "");
```

Comment: Вроде работает!)

Comment: да, работает
но в kotlin нет ".replaceAll", нужно юзать ".replace(" ", "")"

Answer (score 0):

не уверен что вам это нужно но есть метод [totrim();](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_trim.htm)